# Java GUI program called by c++ kills its c++ Console application's main thread when it got closed

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, java-native-interface, console-application

I am creating a simple Win32 console application that loads Java GUI which has it's form file..

However, I got some problem..
Here is a part of code..

```
    if(status != JNI_ERR)
{
    cls = env->FindClass("PWNJava");

    if(cls != 0)
    {
        cout<<"class found!"<<endl;

        mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid);

    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Can't find class\n");
        return;
    }

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
    cout<<"\nJVM Destroyed!!"<<endl;


}
```

Ok.. My problem is that, 
When Java GUI application starts, the console application get stopped.

about a code at a bottom, cout<<"\nJVM Destroyed!!"<

this "JVM Destroyed!!" never shows on Console Windows... Once after I closed Java GUI Application, Console application does not work anymore. it just shows "push any button to close".

the console program seem to be terminated at "jvm->DestroyJavaVM();" line.. so JVM Destroyed message never pops up.

**I even tried it by making a new thread and running java but, it kills my main thread anyway once after I close Java GUI Program.**

How to fix this automatic termination of Console Program by Java Gui Application?

Below is address of downloadable source code: (MSVS 2008 for C++ and Netbeans for Java)
http://cfile209.uf.daum.net/attach/241D3F3D5214C4ED07ECE1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the default close operation of the frame to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. This makes the program terminate - not just the JVM, the *whole* program - when the frame is closed.

Use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` instead of `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

Comment: it worked nice!! just one more question, how can I get same effect when I try to close JAVA GUI application by clicking just normal button? because it seems that "setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);" only works when I click only "X" button, not any button I added on a form. In button Event handler I added there "System.exit(0)" but it terminates my main console together..

Comment: Add an event listener to the button, make the event listener hide the frame (`setVisble(false)`) and then dispose it (`dispose()`).